# Pegar RadioButtons selecionados em WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Tenho vários `radiobuttons` em meu formulário, cada um com um `content` diferente. Como faço para pegar o `radiobuttom` selecionado? Sem ter que fazer um `método` para verificar um por um.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o evento `Checked`:

```
<RadioButton Name="radioButton1" Checked="radioButton_Checked">Opcao 1</RadioButton>
<RadioButton Name="radioButton2" Checked="radioButton_Checked">Opcao 2</RadioButton>
```

Função:

```
private void radioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    opcaoEscolhida = (RadioButton)sender;
}
```

Comment: Show de bola. Obrigado!